# How to remove only group price from all products?

Tags: magento

I have this issue I want to remove all group prices (only this price) from all the products in a magento store, but I am not sure how can I do that. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The quickest way to delete ALL group prices, you could go to the database.

```
DELETE FROM `catalog_product_entity_group_price`;
```

This will remove the stored values for the group pricing.  You then need to follow-up with the full re-index or re-index of 'catalog_product_price' to clear out the group price data of the indexes so they will no longer be used.

Alternatively, if you'd prefer to do it programmatically, you can do it on an individual product like so:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(877);
$product->setGroupPrice(null);
$product->save();
```

And still another alternative:

```
Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_backend_groupprice')->deletePriceData($productId);
```

This last one you will need to do a reindex as well.  The only method you shouldn't have to is with a full product save.

Comment: Great answer, thank you, just to add something for my specific needs if someone other needs it. I had this problem. I had grouped price in almost every product, but I want it to make a global promotion for a specific group. So I made the first part as Ian says (to clear all results from catalog_product_entity_group_price table) and then I went to the promotions page and made a promotion for the specific group and apllied the rules. That solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Following solution for works with **Group prices**

for remove group price need a Price ID

```
$info = Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_attribute_backend_groupprice')->loadPriceData($PRODUCT_ID);
```

and check array, will array with price data

And for remove group price, can try following

```
Mage::getResourceSingleton('catalog/product_attribute_backend_groupprice')->deletePriceData($PRODUCT_ID, null, $PRICE_ID);
```